# how do i change the color of the input text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
 from tkinter import *
import random
a = random.randint(1,10)
print(a)
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title(" peleg's random number")

wrongtxt = "Wrong answer the number was, {}".format(a)
righttxt=  "Correct the number was {}".format(a)


def Take_input():

    INPUT = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c",)
    print(INPUT)
    if (INPUT == format(a)):
        Output.insert(END, righttxt)
    else:
        Output.insert(END, wrongtxt)


l = Label(text="pick a number between 1-10")
inputtxt = Text(root, height=10,
                width=35,
                bg="gray")

Output = Text(root, height=10,
              width=35,
              bg="black")

Display = Button(root, height=2,
                 bg="black",
                 width=20,
                 text="Show",
                 command=lambda: Take_input())

l.pack()
inputtxt.pack()
Display.pack()
Output.pack()

mainloop()
```

my code is pretty simple but i cant seem to find a solution on how to change the color of the text that you input, i meant the text of the input that the user is writing
also how do i change the color of the text of the printed output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fg` parameter:

```
inputtxt = Text(root, height=10,
                width=35,
                bg="gray",
                fg="red")  # <- HERE

Output = Text(root, height=10,
              width=35,
              bg="black",
              fg="red")  # <- HERE
```

**Update**

> How do I do the same thing with the root, I mean the background of the screen?

```
root.configure(background="red")
```

Comment: thanks, it was that simple

Comment: sorry to bother you but how do i do the same thing with the root, i mean the background of the screen,

Comment: You don't bother me at all. `root.configure(background="red")`